# Two different actions on one button

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, jquery, codeigniter-2

I have created a form in my view that calls some method in controller.
I want to do two things on my submit button function:

Use Ajax function to display output on the same page,

Get data (in the same method that is displaying the output) using $this->input->post function

Comment: Either use `Ajax` or use traditional `get`,`post` function.

Comment: I solved my problem. I had to use an iframe. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can write two functions on your button ... For `type="button"`

```
<input type="button" value="Don't show this again! " onclick="function1();function2();" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do using ajax like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "Here is the url path",
    type: "GET",
    data: {},
    beforeSend:function(){
        //do something like loading image
    },
    success:function(response){
        alert(response); //do something
    },
    error:function(e){
        alert("something wrong"+e);
    }
})
```

Comment: in beforeSend function, I want to call a method in my controller and that method is using form values by using this->input->post(), How can I get values using this->input->post?

Comment: @Aman replace type:GET to type:POST then you can able to get the value in post.